# Keyboard settings are missing

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to change a keyboard shortcut but I can't find the keyboard section in Settings.

[image]

When I searched for "keyboard", only these options are shown

[image]

Any idea how I might fix this?

Thanks

--- Addendum ---

Following a suggestion from @vanadium, terminal app output this message:

```
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2216: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.

** (gnome-control-center:116682): WARNING **: 11:38:11.693: Ignoring broken panel keyboard (missing desktop file)

(gnome-control-center:116682): cc-window-WARNING **: 11:38:11.811: Could not find settings panel "keyboard"
```

Comment: Can you launch it from the terminal with the command `gnome-control-center keyboard`? If not, and if error messages display in the terminal, then copy/paste them in your post. Also include any information about your system that may be relevant: is this a fresh install? Is this an upgrade? Did it ever work then stop working? Did something happen at one time, e.g. an unexpected power outage, etc

Comment: See the addendum to my post

Comment: You did not give information of what may have happened to your system, but it appears for one that a default system file, /usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop
is missing. Some reinstallation of system components, or, depending on what happened, the entire desktopt may be in order.

Comment: In answer to what I've done, I can't give specifics as I've been tinkering a lot with my laptop since moving to Linux. The only things I've done recently are: 

* installing a bunch of Gnome extensions
* installing then removing KDE Desktop
* upgrading to 22.10 and then downgrading back to 22.04

Answer (score 1):

removing (`sudo apt remove gnome-control-center`) then reinstalling "gnome-control-center" (`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`), managed to fix the issue.